# What differs BigInteger.Remainder (a,b) from BigInteger.ModPow (a,1,b) in C# language?

Tags: c#, .net

What differs `BigInteger.Remainder(a, b)` from `BigInteger.ModPow(a, 1, b)` in C# language?

Is there a difference between each one if we use opposite numbers, e.g.

```
BigInteger.ModPow (new BigInteger(21), 1, new BigInteger(-5))
```

and

```
BigInteger.Remainder(new BigInteger(21), new BigInteger(-5))
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple test application to see the (any) differences?...

Comment: "hmm. I could use this function that does what I want, or a different function that, in a pathological degenerative case, may operate in the same way. Which one should I use?" - I'm glad I'm not maintaining your code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I completely agree. But it's possible he has this function somewhere in code he has to maintain, and wants to know if there's a reason for it other than stupidity, that is to say whether it is safe to replace it, or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the same as between `int a = 5;` and `int a = Math.Pow(5, 1);`, for example.

According to documentation,

> **`BigInteger.ModPow`**  Performs modulus division on a number raised to the power of another number.
>
> **`BigInteger.Remainder (a,b)`** Performs integer division on two BigInteger values and returns the remainder.

In other words, `ModPow` is **`(a ^ b) % c`** (***`^`** is a pow*) and `Remainder` is **`a % c`**.

If `b` is equal to 1, then they will result in the same value. However, what is the need to use `ModPow`? It makes no sense, while taking some extra computations, **decreasing performance (see "Performance comparison")** and readbility. Use `Remainder` in this case.

If you need a modulus from a power of a BigInteger, the use `ModPow`.

### Performance comparison

Use the following code to benchmark these operations:

```
List<BigInteger> results = new List<BigInteger>();

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    results.Add(BigInteger.ModPow(new BigInteger(21), 1, new BigInteger(-5)));
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"ModPow took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

sw.Restart();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    results.Add(BigInteger.Remainder(new BigInteger(21), new BigInteger(-5)));
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"Modulus took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
```

The output is the following:

```
ModPow took 277 ms
Modulus took 91 ms
```

which demonstrates that you should use `ModPow` only when you actually need a modulus of an integer in N-th power.

Answer (score 1):

There is not only theoretically none, there is also practically none, except ModPow wastes more electricity.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/cZ2LZh

```
using System;

using System.Numerics;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = System.Numerics.BigInteger.ModPow (new System.Numerics.BigInteger(21) ,1,new System.Numerics.BigInteger(-5) ) ;

        var b = BigInteger.Remainder(new BigInteger(21),new BigInteger(-5));

        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

    }
}
```

==>

> 1
>  1
>  Hello World

Comment: There is none difference in result. `Math.Pow(2, 8)` and `250 + 6` produce the same result, but it doesn't mean that there is no difference :)

Comment: @Yeldar Kurmangaliyev: Yes, and just because the description says Remainder and ModPow "do the same", implementation-wise this is not really given, which means the result might be different with some special values (depending on exactly how modulus or pow is implemented).